# Is there something wrong with this post request?

Tags: node.js, express, postman, body-parser

Below is the code I have written to check if a POST can or cannot go in to a database.
Given the Postman request of:

`localhost:8080/api/users?email=user@website.com&password=notpassword&phoneNumber=0987654321`

When the POST is sent by Postman and caught by node, the query is empty. I'm not sure what's going on.

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import db from './db/db';

const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

app.get('/api/users', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send({
        success: 'true',
        message: 'users retrieved successfully.',
        users: db
    });
});

app.post('/api/users', jsonParser, (req, res) => {
    if (!req.body.email) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            success: 'false',
            message: 'An e-mail is required.'
        });
    } else if (!req.body.password) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            success: 'false',
            message: 'A password is required.'
        });
    } else if (!req.body.phoneNumber) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            success: 'false',
            message: 'A phone number is required.'
        });
    } else if (req.body.phoneNumber.len() !== 10) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            success: 'false',
            message: 'The phone number must be 10 digits long, no dashes. (##########)'
        });
    }
    const user = {
        id: db.length + 1,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber
    }
    db.push(user);
    return res.status(201).send({
        success: 'true',
        message: 'User added successfully.',
        user
    });
    console.log(req.body)
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

I literally can't think of any other way to put my problem, other than "Why is the Postman query sent with parameters and caught by node empty?"

Comment: Those values aren't in the *body*, they're query params. But why not put them in the body? Also note you can app.use the JSON parser too.

Comment: I'm picking up when you're putting down, but I don't know exactly how to do that...

Comment: Which part? If you want to access the query parameters, read the Express docs. If you want to send a request body, read the Postman docs.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by [u/jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe), I was not using the Postman option of sending a body in the request, only parameters. Reading the docs is what was required: [POST request in Postman](https://www.toolsqa.com/postman/post-request-in-postman/)